# How Can I load DEVMODE using jna Structure class without garbling

Tags: java, c++, jna

I'm trying to load DEVMODE by Java.

As following the link below, I create a class SampleClass which extends com.sun.jna.Structure.
Inside the SampleClass Constructor, I call #useMemory(Pointer m) and then call #read().
After I call its Constructor, each field have values.
It looks fine but, value of char[] looks garbling.
So I want to know the proper way to load DEVMODE.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183565(v=vs.85).aspx

the garbling field is below.

```
public char[] dmDeviceName = new char[32];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to initialize a `Structure` from an existing `Pointer` is to use the `Pointer`-based constructor, e.g.

```
public class MyClass extends Structure {
    public char[] buffer = new char[32];
    public MyClass(Pointer p) {
        super(p);
        read();
    }
}
```

This avoids a superfluous memory allocation which occurs with the default constructor.

Note that `DEVMODE` has a union field, whose type you should probably set before calling `Structure.read()`.  In this case it probably won't hurt if you don't, since the fields are all primitives, but you'll likely have to manually call `Structure.read()` on the union field.

You can use the system property `-Djna.dump_memory=true` to see the contents of native memory vis a vis your Java fields when you call `toString()` on the `Structure`.  This can help you determine if you're missing a field or padding, or have an incorrectly-sized field type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work in my case.Do I have to care about Character Code? Since I'm using Shift-JIS.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?  Please update your question.

Comment: Make sure you use `byte[]` if your native uses `const char*` and use `char[]` if your native uses `const wchar_t*`.  You'll likely need to decode into a Java String manually in the former case (JNA provides `Native.toString()` to help).

Comment: Problem Solved. I referenced wrong Pointer. Thanks for your help!